# I can't get multiple selected values of select box in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

So, I have an HTML/PHP form that has a select list box from which you can select multiple values because its multiple properties are set to multiple. Consider the form method is 'POST'. But the list box is saving only one value when I click on SUBMIT (to be specific the last value chosen). I don't know why.

This is part of my code:

```html
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitSave'])) {
    // Disable errors due to empty xml files
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING);

        $domDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        $domDoc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $domDoc->formatOutput = true;
        $domDoc->encoding = 'UTF-8';
        $domDoc->load('./data/expression.xml');
        $xpath = new DOMXpath($domDoc);


        if($domDoc->getElementsByTagName('expression')->length>0){
            // If we already have expression tag defined
            $expression = $domDoc->getElementsByTagName('expression')[0];
        }else{
            // If we don't have any expression tag, i.e. file is empty
            $expression = $domDoc->createElement('expression');
        }

    $vocabulario = $domDoc->createElement('vocabulario');
    $vocabulario->setAttribute('word', $_POST['word']);
    $classe = $domDoc->createElement('classe', $_POST['classe']);

    $domDoc->appendChild($expression);
    $expression->appendChild($vocabulario);
    $vocabulario->appendChild($classe);

    file_put_contents('./data/expression.xml', $domDoc->saveXML());
    header('location:index.php');

}
?>

<form method="post">
<div class="col-75">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <select name="classe[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="| adjective |">adjective</option>
    <option value="| adverb |">adverb</option>
    <option value="| noun |">noun</option>
    <option value="| verb |">verb</option>
  </select>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var s2 = $("#classe").select2({
      placeholder: "Select",
      tags: true
    });
  </script>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <td><input type="submit" value="Save" name="submitSave"></td>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to check if actually the multiple select works by output the select values before form submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code work just right for me:

```
/home/vagrant/foo/index.php:3:
array (size=2)
  'classe' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '| adjective |' (length=13)
      1 => string '| adverb |' (length=10)
  'submitSave' => string 'Save' (length=4)
```

have some special config in PHP?

my test:

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);

?>
<form method="POST">
     <div class="col-75">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <select id="classe" name="classe[]" multiple name="event_type[]" class="form-control" required>
  <option value="| adjective |">adjective</option>
  <option value="| adverb |">adverb</option>
  <option value="| noun |">noun</option>
  <option value="| verb |">verb</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var s2 = $("#classe").select2({
    placeholder: "Select",
    tags: true
});


    </script>
</div>
<div class="row">

            <td><input type="submit" value="Save" name="submitSave"></td>
    </div>  
</form>
```

edit:

when yo receive array data in PHP, in your case:

```html
<select name="classes[]" >
```

the PHP var is `$_POST['classes']` not `$_POST['classes[]']` and it is an array, if you want to use it as an string you have to use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php)

Comment: Take a look! I updated my code above. It stills doesn't work. Maybe something is missing in my PHP code.

Comment: your select tag has two name attributes, $_POST['classes'] is an array not a string

Comment: I updated my code, I remove one name attribute, but it stills doesn't work as you suggested above! Could you show me how to change it in my code, please??

Comment: @elba Unfortunately, this piece of code is given by you doesn't resolve my question

Comment: @elba I checked your edit. I put <select name="classe[]" multiple="multiple"> and $_POST['classe'] as you said, but now I got this error message: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode .... Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode

Comment: you must divide you problem `DOMDocument` was not the original problem in your question, the original problem is solved? when you post the form you receive an array of your selected options?

Comment: Yes, I receive it. Thanks. But I need to solve the other problem with DOMDocument to store all the values selected. That's the point of my question. If I change select name attribute from classe to classe[], I got this error that I mentioned above and the page is crashed. If I return to select name = "classe", just one item is saved (the last one chosen).  I want to store all values selected.

Comment: as I say in the answer, you are getting an array not a string, you should use implode to join them in a string